# How to include properties from external file to hibernate.cfg.xml using spring in a standalone app(jar)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jar, properties

I need to be able to store database config properties in an external file that well be used by the application jar and include it  in form of jstl expressions. (like : ${password} etc.)?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  

<hibernate-configuration>  

<session-factory>  
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</property>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:db2://localhost:50001/svntools</property> 
  <property name="connection.username">root</property> 
  <property name="connection.password">root</property> 
  <property name="connection.driver_class">com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</property> 
-->

     <property name="show_sql">true</property>  


 <mapping class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.persistance.eo.BrancheEntity"/>  
 <mapping class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.persistance.eo.RevisionEntity"/>  
 <mapping class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.persistance.eo.ProjectEntity"/>  
 <mapping class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.persistance.eo.StatistiqueEntity"/>  
 <mapping class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.persistance.eo.DomaineEntity"/>  


 </session-factory>  

</hibernate-configuration>
```

SpringConfig.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

```
<bean id="projectDAO" class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.persistance.impl.ProjectDAOImpl">
</bean>
<bean id="reportDAO" class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.persistance.impl.ReportDAOImpl" />
<bean id="brancheDAO" class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.persistance.impl.BrancheDAOImpl" />

<bean id="domaineDAO" class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.persistance.impl.DomaineDAOImpl" />

<bean id="svnKitDa"
    class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.domaine.DA.impl.SVNKitDAImpl" />
<bean id="RevisionServicesBean"
    class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.domaine.impl.RevisionsServicesImpl">
    <property name="svnKitDa" ref="svnKitDa" />
    <property name="brancheDAO" ref="brancheDAO" />
</bean>


<bean id="parser" class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.transvers.utils.ParserImpl" />

<bean id="reportServices"
    class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.service.impl.ReportServicesImpl">
    <property name="reportDAO" ref="reportDAO" />
    <property name="brancheDAO" ref="brancheDAO" />
    <property name="projectDAO" ref="projectDAO" />
    <property name="parser" ref="parser" />
</bean>
<bean id="projectServices"
    class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.service.impl.ProjectServicesImpl">
    <property name="projectDAO" ref="projectDAO" />
</bean>

<bean id="domaineServices"
    class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.service.impl.DomaineServicesImpl">
    <property name="domaineDAO" ref="domaineDAO" />
</bean>

<bean id="generator"
    class="fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.domaine.generatorDocServices.impl.GeneratorDocServiceImpl" />
```

The class that use the session:

```
package fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.persistance.impl;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.persistance.ProjectDAO;
import fr.gouv.education.sirhen.svnreporting.persistance.eo.ProjectEntity;

public class ProjectDAOImpl implements ProjectDAO {

    private static final String Location_Hibernate = 
            "resources/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

     public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }


    public void addProject(ProjectEntity project) {
        File hibernatePropsFile = new File(Location_Hibernate);
         Session session=new Configuration().configure(hibernatePropsFile).buildSessionFactory().openSession();  
           Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();  
           session.saveOrUpdate(project);
           t.commit();
           session.close();  
    }

    public List<ProjectEntity> getProjects() {
        File hibernatePropsFile = new File(Location_Hibernate);
         Session session=new Configuration().configure(hibernatePropsFile).buildSessionFactory().openSession();  
           Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();  

          List<ProjectEntity> projects= session.createCriteria(ProjectEntity.class).list();
           t.commit();  
           session.close();  
           return projects;
    }

    public List<String> getProjectsNames() {
        File hibernatePropsFile = new File(Location_Hibernate);
         Session session=new Configuration().configure(hibernatePropsFile).buildSessionFactory().openSession();  
           Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();  

          List<ProjectEntity> projects= session.createCriteria(ProjectEntity.class).list();
           t.commit();  
           session.close();  
           List<String> ProjectsNames=new LinkedList<String>();
           for( ProjectEntity projet : projects)
           {
               ProjectsNames.add(projet.getName());   
           }
           return ProjectsNames;
    }



}
```

Comment: Hi @Yasser Malek, your ask is not clear enough but still as per my understanding i can provide you an answer

Comment: am developing a standalone app (executable jar) and I want to be able to make db connection info defined in hibernate.cfg parametred from outside the jar using a propertis file

Comment: I will update my answer accordingly you can follow that

Comment: I have edited my question so that you can relate

Comment: you can see that i have updated my answer for use the property file as per your requirement. You can use it in your dao while you using session factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate approach is you can directly use `hibernate.properties` file instead of `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

But if you want to use another file then `hibernate.properties` file then please refer link given below:

[How to read database configuration parameter using properties file in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684785/how-to-read-database-configuration-parameter-using-properties-file-in-hibernate)

Still, if you want to read properties file separate then you can read with normal java code to read properties file from class path or relative file path and set those properties on environment using `ConfigurableEnvironment`  of spring.

## Edited Answer

If you want to read properties file outside of your application (jar) then you can read properties file programmatically from relative file path.
I have provided one answer earlier and that was the same situation for read properties file, You can follow my Edited answer from there.

[Spring Boot embedded Tomcat not loading external properties file in ApplicationListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441183/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-not-loading-external-properties-file-in-applicationl/45445697#45445697)

Now You can use System properties or Environment properties to store properties loaded earlier from relative file path and then it will available any where in the application.

```
@Autowired
private ConfigurableEnvironment  myEnv;
```

or

```
System.setProperty ("propertyName", "propertyValue");
```